# FFMpeg 3.4 with NDK 15c vs FFMpeg 3.4 with NDK 16b

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

Я собрал FFMpeg под ревизией 15c, имеет ли смысл стремится собрать его на ревизии 16b? Я не могу найти ответа на этот вопрос в интернете=(